# Visualizing multiple "histograms" (bar-charts)

Tags: pca, data-visualization, histogram, barplot

I am having difficulties to select the right way to visualize data. Let's say we have **bookstores** that sells **books**, and every book has at least one **category**.

For a bookstore, if we count all the categories of books, we acquire a histogram that shows the number of books that falls into a specific category for that bookstore.

I want to visualize the bookstore behavior, I want to see if they favor a category over other categories. I don't want to see if they are favoring sci-fi all together, but I want to see if they are treating every category equally or not.

I have ~1M bookstores.

I have thought of 4 methods:

1. Sample the data, show only 500 bookstore's histograms. Show them in 5 separate pages using 10x10 grid. Example of a 4x4 grid:

   [image: multiple histograms 1]
2. Same as #1. But this time sort x axis values according to their count desc, so if there is a favoring it will be seen easily.
3. Imagine putting the histograms in #2 together like a deck and showing them in 3D. Something like this:
   [image: 3D histogram]
4. Instead of using third axis suing color to represent colors, so using a heatmap (2D histogram):
   [image: 2D histogram]
   If generally bookstores prefer some categories to others it will be displayed as a nice gradient from left to right.

Do you have any other visualization ideas/tools to represent multiple histograms?

Comment: I think you mean bar charts rather than histograms

Comment: @Rob: Isn't histogram a special type of bar chart that represents a frequency distribution? I am trying to visualize category frequencies for many bookstores.

Comment: @nimcap No, because histogram is over a continuous variable, and book category is a categorical variable.

Comment: @mbq Let's say a book store has 3 books, and their categories are: B1:[c1, c2, c3] B2:[c1, c3] B3:[c1, c4]. When we aggregate the category counts we get [c1 x 3, c2 x 1, c3 x 2, c4 x 1]. Isn't this enough to generate a histogram?

Comment: @nimcap No, it is enough to generate a bar chart. Histogram can be done for instance for a price of a book.

Comment: @mbq I really don't get it, wherever I look it says histogram is about frequencies, can you point to any sources mentioning histogram is for continuous variables.

Comment: @nimcap It is about frequencies that some continuous variable fits in a particular interval (bin). After making the cut of space into bins, it boils down to a bar chart, still with richer interpretation.

Comment: @RobHyndman the example in the question of the distribution of reaction times ought to be a histogram not a bar chart - its just that the example display is ... well, *terrible*.

Comment: I guess this confusion is caused by how excel conceptualizes histograms, as bar  charts with zero space between the bars!

Comment: Have you tried [ridgeline plots](https://www.data-to-viz.com/graph/ridgeline.html)/

Answer (score 12):

As you have found out there are no easy answers to your question!

I presume that you interested in finding strange or different book stores? If this is the case then you could try things like [PCA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53/pca-on-correlation-or-covariance/78#78) (see the wikipedia [cluster analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) page for more details).

To give you an idea, consider this example. You have 26 bookshops (with names A, B,..Z). All bookshops are similar, except:

1. Shop Z sells only a few History books.
2. Shops O-Y sell more romance books than average.

A principal components plot highlights these shops for further investigation.

Here's some sample R code:

```
> d = data.frame(Romance = rpois(26, 50), Horror = rpois(26, 100), 
               Science = rpois(26, 75), History = rpois(26, 125))
> rownames(d) = LETTERS
#Alter a few shops
> d[15:25,][1] = rpois(11,150)
> d[26,][4] = rpois(1, 10)
#look at the data
> head(d, 2)
       Romance Horror Science History
 A      36    107      62     139
 B      47     93      64     118
> books.PC.cov = prcomp(d)
> books.scores.cov = predict(books.PC.cov)
# Plot of PC1 vs PC2
> plot(books.scores.cov[,1],books.scores.cov[,2],
       xlab="PC 1",ylab="PC 2", pch=NA)
> text(books.scores.cov[,1],books.scores.cov[,2],labels=LETTERS)
```

This gives the following plot:

[PCA plot http://img265.imageshack.us/img265/7263/tmplx.jpg](http://img265.imageshack.us/img265/7263/tmplx.jpg)

Notice that:

1. Shop z is an outlying point.
2. The others shops form two distinct groups.

**Other possibilities**

You could also look at [GGobi](http://www.ggobi.org/), I've never used it, but it looks interesting.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. Situation is hard to describe even in my native language :) Let me  try. I am not interested if bookstores are favoring particular categories but I want to see if they favor categories. Actually this is what I am expecting. Let's say I have 3 bookstores (B1, B2, B3) and 4 categories (C1, C2, C3, C4). These are their sales data: B1(1, 1, 20, 20) B2(90, 1, 1, 1), B3(1, 1, 1, 30). Looking at this data I can tell they favor some categories to others. But if data was like B1(20, 30, 20, 20) B2(90, 100, 100, 100), B3(30, 30, 40, 40) I cant say that.

Comment: In my example, shops O-Y favour romance books. This is why these shops are in a distinct group in the PC plot.

Comment: I voted this up as a good general answer but as a practical answer, dealing with that many data points is going to be brutal.

Comment: +1 This is certainly not what OP wants, still it is certainly what she/he should want.

Comment: +1 Nice example of a "down-to-Earth" application of PCA.

Comment: maybe correspondence analysis would be a better bfit than PCA

Comment: Hello. The plot link is not working, I fear.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest something that hasn't got a defined name (probably "parallel plot") and looks like this:

[image]

Basically you plot all counts for all bookstores as points over categories listed on x axis and connect the results from each bookstore with a line. Still this may be too tangled for 1M lines, though. The concept comes from GGobi which was already mentioned by csgillespie.

Comment: Parallel plots depend heavily on the "right" ordering of variables, so for too many categories this will become tedious. And the correct source seems to be A.Inselberg, 1981.

Comment: They're called parallel coordinate plots: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_coordinates

Comment: @Simon thanks; @honk I agree, this is one reason why I don't use them.