# Usage of PCA - how to scale observations?

Tags: pca, scales

I want to use PCA in this kind of situation. I have three variables:

1. how many times something happened for user - positive integer;
2. total "power" of all happened events for user - real number, can be negative
3. percent of "successful hits" - real positive number 0 < x < 1

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) states that "PCA is sensitive to the scaling of the variables."

A problem is that "power" can be measured using various units.
And choice of units will affect the results. I do not see a natural choice of units for the moment.

**Are there any suggestions on how to scale observations for PCA?**

Comment: Did you read some advice for a [similar question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/12200/3277)?

Answer (score 2):

You could first shift the data by substracting the respective mean values to each of the columns, and then rescale the resulting values so that they fall within the interval [-1,1]

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! Yes, mean subtraction is necessary, but what is appropriate scaling - should I scale everything to -1 1 or only part of variables - it is not so clear... Choosing different scaling for different variables - gives different "importance" for different variables - it should depend on task what is the appropriate "importance", but I do not see the right one in my case...

Comment: Although this recommendation might work for some datasets, it is exquisitely sensitive to any outliers that might exist, and so is not a good general procedure.

Comment: very true! otherwise you could normalize the variance of each component individually to one

Comment: @AlexanderChervov I meant it as: $$x -> (x-mean(x))/(max(x)-min(x))$$, so that the variable now lies in the interval $$[-1,1]$$