# Scaling Variables in PCA, yet all on the same scale

Tags: pca, normalization

I know this topic of scaling and normalizing variables for PCA has been posted on a lot, [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69157/), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53), [3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12200). However, I am performing PCA on coordinate data that is measured all on the same scale, i.e. (x,y) data. Would I have to standardize or normalize this data to account for the variance? Or is that not necessary since the variables are measured on the same scale.

I tested an instance within my data and found that when I do not scale or normalize the data, I explain 73.8% of the variance in the x direction and 26.1% of the variance in the y direction. When I scale the data, 88.6% in the x and 11.4% in the y. Normalizing the data doesn't effect the results when there is no scaling because the coordinate data is the range from [0,100], which can be scaled to [0,1].

To be specific, I am performing PCA on coordinate data of individual players to find their area. So I have all the xy data of each player in a set. **Before I run PCA on each player I would scale the entire dataset.** Then I filtered to get the player, applied PCA, extracted the standard deviation, then used the ellipsoidal area equation to find the area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a good question, and one that I’ve encountered a number of times at work. The short answer is it cannot hurt to scale even when input variables are all on same scale (in your case 0-100).

When input variables to your model have smaller values, in the range of 0-1, training speed can increase and potential problems of getting stuck in local optimas (in case of neural networks) can be avoided. You may also have identical scales for your input variables but with various means and standard deviations, and so is not standardized.

You were right to test scaling vs not as to inform any differences. As you revealed, scaling provided more explanation of variance. Ultimately in PCA you attempting to draw out components that most explain variance in your data. If scaling helps you to identify that, and something like Factor Analysis can be used to confirm it, then scaling is beneficial for your use case.