# When and why to use scale function (in R) in PCA analysis?

Tags: pca, scales

I understand that if the scale of the different variables varies(for example, some expressed in absolute form while other in percentages), that will cause problem in Principal component analysis (PCA). I read two PCA analysis that first use scale() function to standlize the dataset: 1) [from R action](http://www.r-statistics.com/2013/08/k-means-clustering-from-r-in-action/) 2) 
[from R bloggers](http://www.r-bloggers.com/pca-and-k-means-clustering-of-delta-aircraft/).

My question is, if I want to do **PCA for variables expressed in terms of percentages. Do I want to still use scale function?** It feel like the percentages already were normalized and can be used directly. Can anyone explain why to use scale function?

The variables are social-economic factors, including count of school numbers, population density, housing unit density, green space area percentage, etc. They are mostly expressed in terms of percentages, ranging from 0 to 100%. For the variables not in percentage (e.g., count of school number), I converted them using value/max value, so that they finally all range from 0 to 100%.

**Updates:**

Thanks to Whuber's suggestion, I see that: "standardization makes a difference in the results but isn't absolutely necessary".

1) Useful posts to understand [PCA correlation covariance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=PCA%20correlation%20covariance)

2) [Whether to normalize data before PCA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105592/not-normalizing-data-before-pca-gives-better-explained-variance-ratio)

Comment: Could you tell us more about your percentages? For instance, maybe one variable is concentration of a contaminant in water and ranges from $0$ to $0.000\,000\,01\%$; maybe another is a mortality rate in a dose-response test ranging from $0$ to $100\%$; maybe another is percent increase in a quantity year-over-year and ranges from $-100\%$ to over $1000\%$. You see the point: merely expressing a number as a percentage does not, in itself, automatically put it on any standard scale. More information about the *variation* of the variable is needed. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53.

Comment: Hi whuber, all variables range from 0 to 100%.

Comment: That's helpful but it's not enough to know that. For instance, maybe one of your water concentrations is $100\%$ and all the others are still less than $0.000\,000\,01\%$. Since PCA uses variances and covariances, you want to pay attention to those rather than the ranges of your data.

Comment: Hi whuber, are you suggesting to examine the distribution of each variable? I think their variance would certainly vary from each other. So does that mean using scale() function is often a necessity for PCA analysis?

Comment: The link I gave you--along with other posts you can find by searching our site for [PCA correlation covariance](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=PCA+correlation+covariance)--will explain that standardization *makes a difference in the results* but isn't absolutely necessary. In fact, there are even more ways to normalize data for a PCA: which one you choose depends on the nature of the data and what you intend to do with the result.

Comment: Hi whuber, thanks again for your inputs. I rethink my question and post a continuing thought. Can I invite you to comment? here:http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158342/data-preparation-for-clustering-analysis