# Is normalization required in Sammon mapping

Tags: normalization, multidimensional-scaling

I have a data set of 480 samples with 7-dimensions and I want to implement a [Sammon mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sammon_mapping) into 3-dimensions. In [Principal Component Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) to my understanding we need to normalize the data in order to prevent features with large scales dominating the component selection.

In Sammon mapping however I'm not sure should normalization (e.g. z-score) be applied or not. Should data be normalized in Sammon mapping? If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sammon-mapping is form of multidimensional scaling, the 'general' rules apply considering normalisation and unsupervised learning.

Sammon-mapping tries to minimize the following error-function: 
$E = \sum_{i<j}\frac{1}{d^{*}_{ij}}\sum_{i<j}\frac{(d^{*}_{ij}-d_{ij})^2}{d^{*}_{ij}}$, with $d^{*}_{ij}$ being the distance between points $i$ and $j$ in the original space and $d_{ij}$ the distance between points $i$ and $j$ in the projected space.

If your features are not normalized, $d^{*}_{ij}$ will be more influenced by features on larger scales, if they are normalized, all features get an equal weight, resulting in a different $d^{*}_{ij}$. Of course, if it makes sense not to normalize your data, that is, it makes sense to compare the data on the scales they are represented, then you shouldn't normalize. This is application-dependent.

A number of general answers concerning the application of normalisation in an unsupervised setting can be found, see for example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105592/not-normalizing-data-before-pca-gives-better-explained-variance-ratio) or [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6715/is-it-necessary-to-standardize-your-data-before-clustering).