# How to use slopes in PCA?

Tags: r, pca, normalization, dimensionality-reduction, scales

I would like to use slope values in PCA. The problem I face is that the slopes I calculate per group could be within different ranges of values. We know that it is important to normalize your data before PCA discussed here: [Why do we need to normalize data before principal component analysis (PCA)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69157/why-do-we-need-to-normalize-data-before-principal-component-analysis-pca). So my groups could have values within a range of 0 to 1 or for example 1-10 (these are examples). So let's assume I have 5 ID's with each 4 features. Each ID has 10 observations per feature, but these could be within different ranges. Here I created some reproducible data:

```
set.seed(7)
df = data.frame(ID = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 10),
                time = c(1:10),
                V1 = c(runif(10, 0, 1), sample(5:20, 10, replace=T), runif(10, 0.2, 0.5), sample(1:100, 10, replace=T), sample(1:20, 10, replace=T)),
                V2 = c(runif(10, 0, 0.2), runif(10, 0, 0.3), sample(1:10, 10, replace=T), runif(10, 0.2, 0.3), runif(10, 0.7, 0.9)),
                V3 = c(runif(10, 0, 0.4), sample(1:10, 10, replace=T), runif(10, 0.2, 0.3), sample(1:10, 10, replace=T), runif(10, 0.5, 0.8)),
                V4 = c(runif(10, 0, 0.1), sample(1:5, 10, replace=T), runif(10, 0.2, 0.9), sample(1:20, 10, replace=T), runif(10, 0.5, 1)))
```

Now we calculate the slopes for each ID for each feature like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(factoextra)
slopes = df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = V1:V4) %>%
  group_by(ID, name) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(modelout = map(data, ~lm(value ~ time, data = .x) %>%
                          tidy %>%
                          filter(term == "time") %>%
                          select(slope = estimate))) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  summarise(slope = unique(slope)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = slope) %>%
  column_to_rownames('ID')
slopes
#>             V1            V2           V3           V4
#> A -0.004548211  0.0023702846 -0.005529712  0.002792688
#> B  0.660606061  0.0013715805 -0.200000000 -0.278787879
#> C -0.003737507  0.2666666667  0.001533572 -0.026828235
#> D  6.084848485 -0.0003168725  0.236363636 -0.757575758
#> E -0.054545455  0.0005361159  0.003567638  0.012812879
```

Let's check PCA results:

```r
res_pca = prcomp(slopes)
res_pca
#> Standard deviations (1, .., p=4):
#> [1] 2.692459114 0.139136216 0.104503624 0.001634561
#> 
#> Rotation (n x k) = (4 x 4):
#>            PC1        PC2         PC3         PC4
#> V1  0.99196373 0.04004058  0.02126357 -0.11812097
#> V2 -0.01267253 0.50183843 -0.86005381 -0.09113202
#> V3  0.04364794 0.67949821  0.32636990  0.65563689
#> V4 -0.11807716 0.53370134  0.39158396 -0.74019096
fviz_eig(res_pca)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As we can see the first component has a big contribution probably due to the scale problem. I also found this [PCA with variables in different Likert scales](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224813/pca-with-variables-in-different-likert-scales), but I think the difference here is that for mine the scales could also differ within each feature.

So I don't know how you should `scale` these kinds of values within ranges for PCA. Could anyone please explain how to normalize this kind of problem?

---

**Edit: clarification**

I think the problem I may face is that I have multiple ID's per variable V1, V2 and each ID has a different range 0-1 and 5-20 (these are examples that could be anything). I would like to calculate the slope for each ID of each variable, but when I calculate it with these values, the IDs with a wider range will have more contribution in the PCA. Let's see the distribution of V1:

```r
set.seed(7)
df = data.frame(ID = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 10),
                time = c(1:10),
                V1 = c(runif(10, 0, 1), sample(5:20, 10, replace=T), runif(10, 0.2, 0.5), sample(1:100, 10, replace=T), sample(1:20, 10, replace=T)),
                V2 = c(runif(10, 0, 0.2), runif(10, 0, 0.3), sample(1:10, 10, replace=T), runif(10, 0.2, 0.3), runif(10, 0.7, 0.9)))
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = V1, fill = ID)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  labs(title = 'Distribution of V1')
```

[image]

As you can see, for example, ID D has a bigger range. This will mean that it has a higher slope which will result in a different contribution, but each slope should have an equal contribution within each variable. But they could have different contributions across variables.

I think my question is how to **normalize** these slopes within each variable? To have an equal contribution of each slope within each variable, otherwise, the PCA will be misleading I think right?

Comment: Your `slopes` are computed with a long chain of commands connected via pipes. Could you formulate it in an easier way. Is it maybe just the correlation table that you compute? And your V1, V2, V3, V4 are neither very clear what you are doing. Those are a long command as well. Possibly you could give an example with two variables and explain it with a plot/diagram.

Comment: Hi @SextusEmpiricus, Thank you for your comment! I edited my question above with some clarification. I think my main question is how to normalize each slope within each variable to perform PCA. Please let me know if it is not clear, thanks!

Comment: You could use a tool like Boruta's random forest to get variable importance and use that for weights.  It doesn't care about scaling at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at least partially mitigated if you standardize *before* computing the slopes.

```
df[,-1] = scale(df[,-1],center = T,scale = T)
slopes = df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = V1:V4) %>%
  group_by(ID, name) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(modelout = map(data, ~lm(value ~ time, data = .x) %>%
                          tidy %>%
                          filter(term == "time") %>%
                          select(slope = estimate))) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  summarise(slope = unique(slope)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = slope) %>%
  column_to_rownames('ID')
res_pca = prcomp(slopes)
res_pca
Standard deviations (1, .., p=4):
[1] 0.434278053 0.133935718 0.097441635 0.001016885

Rotation (n x k) = (4 x 4):
           PC1        PC2           PC3         PC4
V1  0.84169164 0.05809774  0.0003982831 -0.53682369
V2 -0.09243915 0.86245718  0.4949728571 -0.05122969
V3  0.24846072 0.46867888 -0.7247261007  0.43974931
V4 -0.47040138 0.18202298 -0.4793472552 -0.71820358
```

[image]

More fundamentally, the question is, *why* is there so much variability in your variables between IDs? Is it meaningful, or should you be accounting for other sources of variance before estimating your slopes?