# Transform the data before applying PCA

Tags: pca, data-transformation

Do we need to transform data before implement PCA to the raw data? Or it just acceptable if we proceed to used PCA to the raw data?

Comment: Have you already searched this site? This isn't the kind of question that has a general answer and you haven't provided sufficient details. This might be helpful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53/pca-on-correlation-or-covariance

Comment: Or search on Google for "stackexchange pca transform".

Comment: I vote to close as unclear because this is impossible to answer in such a generality.