# When applying PCA to a dataset consisting of regression coefficients, should one use PCA on correlation or on covariance?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, unsupervised-learning

This is a follow-up question from the post: [PCA on correlation or covariance?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53/pca-on-correlation-or-covariance)

The accepted answer quotes:

> You tend to use the covariance matrix when the variable scales are
>   similar and the correlation matrix when variables are on different
>   scales.

I have a data set that are coefficients of a linear model. Let's say $c_1, c_2, \cdots, c_n$. This means they are dimensionless and were obtained by regression. I computed the correlation among the coefficients and found out that the maximum correlation is 0.88 while lowest is -0.79.

I also made a boxplot and the results showed that the variance in some coefficients are larger and some are smaller.

I wanted to know which would be more appropriate to use: PCA cov or correlation?

Comment: Are your scales similar? If yes, covariance and correlation will be equivalent. If not, correlation will be equivalent to scaled covariance. Always use correlation to be on the safe side.

Comment: Most of them are $|c| \leq 1$. But there are some values like 3 or 4. But nothing like 200. So it is hard to judge because these are dimensionless constants.