# Standardized vs. unstandardized PCA

Tags: r, pca, exploratory-data-analysis

I performed PCA using two different R functions fviz() and ggbiplot() to improve the visualization of data. The sum of the first two PC is equal between the two methods, but there is a different value of variance explained for these principal components depending on the method. The ggbiplot() gives standardized PC1 & PC2, which I don't quite understand!

When are standardized PC important to use? If not, then how can I restore the PC values for ggbiplot()?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53/pca-on-correlation-or-covariance?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://github.com/vqv/ggbiplot), `ggbiplot()` is just a visualization function and doesn't not actually calculate principal components.  The first argument supplied to `ggbiplot()` is an object returned by `prcomp()` (or `princomp()`).  `prcomp()` provides two arguments to control whether data are centered (`center`, default is `TRUE`) and scaled (`scale.`, default is `FALSE`).  Generally, centering and scaling are advised, in particular if your original data has very different scales for the columns.  If they are not scaled to unit variance, `prcomp()` still works, but the principal components returned will also have very different scales, making visualization less intuitive.

Comment: There are pros and cons to standardization for PCA. I think there is not a reason to *automatically* choose one or another. See: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53/pca-on-correlation-or-covariance

Comment: Well, I did say "Generally, centering and scaling are advised..." and refer to the differences in scale as a potential issue, as mentioned in the linked thread.  I did not bring up covariance vs correlation, which the linked thread does describe.  I do yield that "automatically" choosing on or another is not advised, and the linked thread does a far better job of fully exploring the option that I did in my short answer.